# Razor Engine Email Template Error Object type cannot be converted to target

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, templates

I want to use RazorEngine to create Email Message, but when my application works on server returns error

> StackTrace:
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.CrossAppDomainCleanUp.CleanupHelper.Init(AppDomain
>   domain, IPrinter printer) at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.CrossAppDomainCleanUp.InitHelper.CreateHelper()
>   at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.ExecutionContextLessThread.FuncConv1.Call(Boolean
>   data) at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.ExecutionContextLessThread.CallHelperSafeHelper2.AsAction()
>   at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.ExecutionContextLessThread.CallHelperSafeHelper2.AsContextCallback(Object
>   state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.ExecutionContextLessThread.DefaultCallFunc[O](Func1
>   f) at RazorEngine.Compilation.CrossAppDomainCleanUp..ctor(AppDomain
>   toWatch, IPrinter printer) at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.CrossAppDomainCleanUp.CreateInitial() at
>   System.Lazy1.CreateValue() --- End of stack trace from previous
>   location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Lazy1.getValue() at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.CrossAppDomainCleanUp.getCurrentCleanup() at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.CrossAppDomainCleanUp.RegisterCleanup(String
>   item, Boolean throwOnDefault) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.InvalidatingCachingProvider.<>c.<.ctor>b50(String
>   item) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.InvalidatingCachingProvider.CacheTemplate(ICompiledTemplate
>   template, ITemplateKey templateKey) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.DefaultCachingProvider.CacheTemplate(ICompiledTemplate
>   template, ITemplateKey templateKey) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineService.CompileAndCacheInternal(ITemplateKey
>   key, Type modelType) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineService.GetCompiledTemplate(ITemplateKey
>   key, Type modelType, Boolean compileOnCacheMiss) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineService.RunCompile(ITemplateKey key,
>   TextWriter writer, Type modelType, Object model, DynamicViewBag
>   viewBag) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.DynamicWrapperService.RunCompile(ITemplateKey
>   key, TextWriter writer, Type modelType, Object model, DynamicViewBag
>   viewBag) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineServiceExtensions.<>cDisplayClass160.b__0(TextWriter
>   writer) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineServiceExtensions.WithWriter(Action1
>   withWriter) at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineServiceExtensions.RunCompile(IRazorEngineService
>   service, String name, Type modelType, Object model, DynamicViewBag
>   viewBag) at project.Email.CreateEmail(List1 offers) 
>   Message:Object type cannot be converted to target.

This is my code, where is error.

```
private string CreateEmail(List<EmailOffer>  offers)
{
   string template=File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, "Views\\EmailTemplate\\Email.cshtml"));
   return Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, offers);
}
```

This is class EmailOffer

```
public class EmailOffer
{
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string UrlImage { get; set; }
}
```

This is Template Email (file cshtml)

```
@model IEnumerable<project.Models.EmailOffer>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <table style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 25px;background-color: #f3f3f3;padding: 10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="max-width: 128px;padding-right: 10px;height: auto;min-width: 64px;width: 20%;"><img src="@item.UrlImage" style="max-width: 100%;" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <h2 style="line-height: 1.1;margin: 10px;font-weight: 500;font-size: 16px;">@item.Title</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I this resolve? Thank you very much.

Comment: The best answer you can get on basis of the information you provided is: "Fix your application. This will resolve your problem".

Comment: I am getting the same error. Not sure what the cause is. Unit Testing works fine.

Comment: Any udpate? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to specify the type of model you're passing in to the RunCompile method?

e.g. from this documentation: 
https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateBasics.html

```
private string CreateEmail(List<EmailOffer>  offers)
{
   string template=File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, "Views\\EmailTemplate\\Email.cshtml"));
   return Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", typeof(List<EmailOffer>), offers);
}
```

Also, you could try fully qualifying the type contained in the collection in the template file, e.g.

```
@foreach (project.Models.EmailOffer item in Model)
{
    ...
}
```